# Trackpad cursor moving around on its own and clicking anywhere

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, cursor

I own a Macbook Pro Late 2011 model and recently the trackpad's cursor is behaving weirdly - it moves around on its own and it clicks anywhere.

I am guessing I need to change my trackpad ?

[link](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009--Mid-2012-Trackpad/IF163-025-1)
Will the trackpad on above link help me ? Do I need to check model number A1278 ?

or just 'Mid-2009--Mid-2012' is good enough to assume it will work with my laptop.

Comment: Check your list of connected bluetooth devices to make sure you don't have another mouse connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, the part you linked should work with your MacBook Pro. Before purchasing a new trackpad, I would suggest you try a few troubleshooting steps.

1. **Reset the SMC**

Resetting the SMC can resolve some problems on a Mac, particularly hardware issues.

Possibly using an external mouse, shut down your Mac.  Then hold the <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> keys along with the power button. After holding these keys for 10 seconds, let go of them and power on your Mac normally. If this does not help, try using Safe Boot.

You can find out more about resetting the SMC here: [How to reset the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201295)

2. **Safe Boot**

In this case, you wouldn't want to stay booted into Safe Mode, but you can still benefit from what Safe Mode does to narrow down the source of the issue. [According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201262), Safe Boot does the following things:

> - Verifies your startup disk and attempts to repair directory issues,    if needed
> - Loads only required kernel extensions
> - Prevents startup items and login items from opening automatically
> - Disables user-installed fonts
> - Deletes font caches, kernel cache, and other system cache files

To boot into Safe Mode, first shut down your Mac. Then press the power button to power on your device while holding the left <kbd>shift</kbd> key on the internal keyboard. Once you see either the login window or your desktop, you can reboot the Mac normally

Just verifying the startup disk and clearing caches can be helpful. I had a very similar case, even with a similar model Mac, where this resolved the issue. If the issue only occurs outside of Safe Mode, then that is also helpful to know.

### **If that doesn't work**

If neither of these things resolve the issue, then I would suggest you take your Mac to an Apple store for a repair estimate. If you would rather perform the repair yourself, the linked part should be compatible with your Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The trackpad of my old Sony laptop sometimes behaved weirdly too. In my case, the reason was dirty and oily surface. It always disappeared after wiping with soap and then with water (be careful!).

Answer (score 1):

For those stumbling across this question with similar issues, I'm adding a few other things to check for:

- MacBooks/iBooks: A battery that is starting to inflate may be exerting pressure from below. Usually this can be felt by trying to click the trackpad - does it click early, not at all, give some weird resistance to pushing?
- Dirt along the edges of the trackpad, or moisture may cause weird behaviour as well. Cleaning with alcohol while the device is switched off is worth giving a try. Make sure there is no liquid left from the process when switching on again. (Alcohol residues fade a lot quicker than moisture)
- Are there any other devices that could be malfunctioning or having side effects? I've had a wacom tablet hidden under some paper and the pen beloging to it hapharzadly tossed on top. Did work s designed, and kept dragging the cursor to the pen-position. Took embarrasingly long to discover! (Booted into safe mode, then checked what would have been running and might have the potential of disrupting mouse action.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I think it was because of atmospheric conditions. I later kept my laptop in a Air Conditioned room for a night and it started working. I tried everything but at last it started working after being cooled in Air Condition.